# how can I format a date in java with "ff"?

Tags: java, date, date-formatting

I'm trying to print a date with the following format:

```
"HHmmssff"
```

I'm using `SimpleDateFormatter`.
It fails because it can't recognize `"ff"`.
Is there another formatter that can?
Or any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S gives you millisecond:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat ("hhmmssS");
```

with substring, you may cut off the last 2 digits:

```
String d = formatter.format (new Date ());
System.out.println (d.substring (0, 7));
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for printing second in fractions (milliseconds), this example will be helpful.

```
public class DateFormatter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy, hh:mm:ss.SSS a");
        String today = formatter.format(date);
        System.out.println("Today : " + today);
    }
}
```

Output:
Today : Tuesday, 24 May 2011, 07:23:30.627 PM

**You see SSS in the formatter returns fractions of seconds for you.**

Comment: SSS are the milliseconds, so it's nearly want you want; there's just an extra digit to cut off (must be truncated according to <a href="ss64.com/ps/syntax-dateformats.html">ss64.com/ps/syntax-dateformats.html</a>, not rounded).  So just add in the code above `today = today.substring(0, today.length() - 2);`

Comment: @toto There is no need of doing substring to remove AM/PM that came from the formatter character 'a'.<br> Just remove 'a' from the formatter. i.e., formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss.SSS")

Answer (score 2):

`f` is not a valid value for `SimpleDateFormat`.

`F` means *Day of week in month*, that might be what you are looking for.

Comment: @dan, that is not Java.  Look here instead: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: If you want fractions of a second use Milliseconds in the formatter.

Comment: @dan, there is not a specific fraction of a second, instead use SSS for milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for `FF` instead of `ff`, as used [here](http://www.java-connect.com/date/SimpleDateFormat-Day-Of-Week-In-Month-Example.html)?